# Using iFrame to show each PDF in a folder

Tags: iframe, foreach

I want to be able to loop through all of the PDFs in a folder and iFrame each of them (like thumbnails) or have a single iFrame and a hyperlink list of all files so that whichever file I choose to look at is loaded into the iFrame.

Since I am unskilled in programming I can create a single iFrame but don't know how to create a correct loop or how to format so it looks appropriate, etc.  Thank you in advance for any provided guidance - I just want my job to run a little smoother and this would help a lot I think.

Comment: So what I had stabbed at before was making a table of contents and a single iFrame so when i clicked an entry on the table on contents the iFrame would be reloaded.

The table of contents was hard-coded and therefore not able to reassess if content has been added or deleted while reloading the "table of contents" on a page refresh.

I hope that helps a little?

Comment: Let me stab that and see where I get - thank you for the push then I can post some code.